# I can't install pygsheets

Tags: python, pip, google-api-python-client, pygsheets

When I tried to execute script, I got following error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-api-python-client>=2.50.0 (from pygsheets==2.0.6) (from versions: 1.0beta5prerelease, 1.0beta5prerelease2, 1.0a1, 1.0a2, 1.0a3, 1.0a4, 1.0a5, 1.0a6, 1.0a7, 1.0a8, 1.0a9, 1.0a10, 1.0a11, 1.0b1, 1.0b2, 1.0b3, 1.0b4, 1.0b5, 1.0b6, 1.0b7, 1.0b8, 1.0b9, 1.0rc1, 1.0rc2, 1.0rc3, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.7.12, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.12.4, 1.12.5, 1.12.6, 1.12.7, 1.12.8, 1.12.10, 1.12.11)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for google-api-python-client>=2.50.0 (from pygsheets==2.0.6)

I was used pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib already but it was error as before

Now I want to install Pygsheets

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: i used python311

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing it and it worked. using this following command

```
pip install pygsheets
```

If it didn't work, you can try installing from pycharm. By following [this method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcWyip8u4rI) to install libs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an old script. It appears there was a big update to pygsheets from 1.x to 2.x that is not backwards compatible. (See https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#version-2-0-0)

So if you're using an old install in the non-upgraded world, you may need to specify version like

```
pip install pygsheets==1.1.3
```